# How can I remove a ghost image while dragging?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I try to remove the ghost image of a drag and drop action in React.

I read about using `event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(new Image(), 0, 0);` to remove the dragged image. However, this method can only be called with `onDragStart`.

I need to use `onDragOver` or `onDragEnter` (both works) as I am dragging across multiple items, but setting both `onDragStart` and `onDragOver` on the `<div>` to be dragged disables `onDragOver` (and also `onDragEnter`) behavior.

Is there any way to combine both methods or to remove the ghost image in another way?

Thank you for your help!